# Anchor links in HTML documents

Tags: html, anchor

At this URL
    **boiseresturants.com/mexican/baja-fresh-mexican-grill.html**

I have an anchor link that looks like

```
<a href="#takemehere">his is a test</a>
```

Now I expected the above link to appear as
   **boiseresturants.com/mexican/baja-fresh-mexican-grill.html#takemehere**

But it points to
    **boiseresturants.com/#takemehere**

Why is this happening? I have never seen something like this before.

Comment: [Formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Select the code in your question and click the "code" (looks like a double Quotes) to properly display the code. Or put the code in backticks (the key usually above the tab key).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's jumping to the home page is because the page has `<base>` set in the `<head>`:

```
<base href="http://www.boiseresturants.com/" />
```

Either drop that or be more specific with your anchors like so:

```
<a href="/mexican/baja-fresh-mexican-grill.html#takemehere">Take Me Here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`base`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/base) element is causing that unexpected behaviour...

```
<base href="http://www.boiseresturants.com/" />
```

You'll need to use the full path.